# Calling derived constructor from base static method

Tags: c++

I would like to know if there would be a way to instantiate a derived class from a static method defined on its base class. For now I have wrapped method in a templated struct. Ideally I would like to do something like this:

```
class Base {
public:
    Base(){}
    virtual ~Base(){}
    static void do_something() {
        Base b(); // should call Derived() instead
        // use our object
    } 
}

class Derived: public Base {
public:
    Derived(): Base() {}
    ~Derived(){}
}

// The idea would be to use the derived static method like that
int main(){
    Derived::do_something();
}
```

Comment: Will there be other classes that are derived from `Base`?

Comment: If it's always going to be `Derived` then just use `Derived`. If not then you're likely a candidate for CRTP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: Yes there are at least 3

Comment: I will look into it thank you

Comment: Depending on what all you want to do, I suggest making it protected and changing it to `static void do_something(Base&)`.  Then in you derived classes you you make a a public override that calls the protected version with the correct class.

Comment: @Adam CRTP is actually what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: Why not calling a pure virtual factory method inside do_something() that creates the right object inside each derived class??

Comment: @Gupta you'd have to write that factory method for every derived class. CRTP is also completely static and has no virtual method call overhead. You could even remove the `virtual` destructor from `Base`. If that's not important then yes you absolutely could.

Comment: @Gupta something like `static virtual Base * create_element() = 0;` and calling it in `do_something();` It would mean I would need to call `new` in the factories which would cost some overhead?

Comment: @AlexandreSenges no the factories could just return objects, i.e. `static virtual Base create_element() = 0;`

Comment: If calling a new operator is considered as an overhead in your case, then go for the templates as suggested by @Adam. But I personally will go for "static polymorphism" iff I have a STRONG reason for that.

Comment: @Adam, No. The factories should return pointers.

Comment: Just in passing, note that `Base b();` declares a function named `b` that takes no arguments and returns an object of type `Base`. To create an object, just use `Base b;`.